# How to place caption (figure / table) into margin?

Tags: latex, margin, caption

I write thesis and need to put a lot of small pictures into it. I also need to use captions (with labels) for better navigation and referring to these pictures. In the same time I want to spare space and put captions beside (next to) pictures, in margin, like marginpar does. I tried sidecap package but it didn't work, neither mcaption package did help. Maybe using a minipage would solve it, but I would like also to align caption to the middle (vertical align) of picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To put relevant stuff in the margin that actually should go to print doesn't sound like a super-good idea to me... Have you really considered all other options?

Comment: Have you tried the following option `\usepackage[margincaption]{sidecap}`? Since in general it sounds like a problem to tackle with the `sidecap` or `caption` packages.

Comment: aioobe: It may not be a super-good idea, but I would like to do it in that way. I don't use any text in captions, just numbers which are sufficient for navigation.

mropa: Thanks for the hint but I have already tried this and it didn't work. This feature is not documented and when I was trying that, it gave me some errors. Maybe I should investigate and try to solve this problem again.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working in my thesis with:

```
\usepackage[margincaption,outercaption,ragged,wide]{sidecap}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{t} 
\sidecaptionvpos{table}{t}
```

and then working with

```
\begin{SCfigure}[][htb]
  ...
\end{SCfigure}
```

Also, you can style the caption with the `caption` package like so:

```
\captionsetup[SCfigure]{format=plain, ...}
```

(same for `SCtable`)